# Aurelia - Trying to switch root and it cannot find the location

Tags: aurelia

I have been following a variety of sources in particular Mathew James Davis with [THIS](http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-auth-pt2/) blog entry and others.

I had in my boot.ts (main in other examples etc):

```
    aurelia
        .start()
        .then(function () { return aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("public/public/public")); });

    });
```

which worked.

I am now running two roots and checking if a JWT exists in localstorage. It gets the jwt and stores it OK and I even obtain it correctly but it now doesnt recognise the root and I think I have a syntax error of some sort..

This is what I now have:

```
aurelia.start().then(() => {
    var auth = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
    let root = auth.isAuthenticated() ? 'app/app/app' : 'public/public/public';
    return aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName(root));
});
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to find module with ID: public/public/public
```

I do not know why it now doesnt work when the exact same path worked when entered directly..

**UPDATE**

Ok so I thought I would refactor this and utilise the section of code that works:

This is what I changed it to:

```
var auth = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
let authenticated = auth.isAuthenticated();
console.log("authenticated: ", authenticated);


if (authenticated) {
    aurelia
        .start()
        .then(function () { return aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("app/app/app")); });
} else {
    aurelia
        .start()
        .then(function () { return aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName("public/public/public")); });
}
```

Now it shows a blank loading page with "loading" and shows this at in the console:

```
authenticated:  false
aurelia-logging-console.js:27 INFO [aurelia] Aurelia Started

client.js:82 [HMR] connected
```

Note - if just have the original code with app/app/app in it and authentication= true then it also shows correctly.

So both roots work but not with a check..

Comment: This is not something I have introduced. I created a vanilla asp.net spa project and then changed the aurelia.start function to:     aurelia.start().then(() => {
        var root: string  = 'app/components/app/app'
        aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName(root))
    });  Again I get the same error - not able to find module.  So it was there before I even started.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this. I eventually changed my original code:

```
aurelia.start().then(function () {
var auth = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
var root = auth.isAuthenticated() ? "app/app/app" : "public/public/public";
aurelia.setRoot(root);
```

to:

```
  aurelia.start().then(() => {
    var auth = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
    let root: string = auth.isAuthenticated() ? PLATFORM.moduleName('app/app/app') : PLATFORM.moduleName('public/public/public');

    aurelia.setRoot(root, document.body)
});
```

and it now works. In the end it was my lack of programming skills however if anybody else has a problem they might try this for switching routes.

Comment: If I remember correctly, PLATFORM.moduleName gets used at compile/bundle time - the bundler makes sure that what you have asked for is available as a resource with the name you have given it. If you're using a variable, the bundler won't be able to use it